# Can I use google authentication without using Google APIs client library for Python?

Tags: python, google-authentication

I'm implementing Google Authentication on my website

https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow

Can I implement it without installing the Google API ("Step 8: Initialize the Google API client library and start the Google+ service")?

For Facebook authentication I communicate directly with Facebook, for example

```
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends/?access_token="+access_token
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

I'm hoping for something similar for Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Google offers OAuth2 authentication which should do what you want.

Here's the documentation: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Although I would recommend using a oauth2 library to authenticate instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thank you! That led me to the urls: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#formingtheurl